# How to Iterate through SET in Angular 2

Tags: angular, rest, angular2-forms, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am writing an application which has got **RESTful web services** for backend connecting with the **mysql** db and front end is in **Angular2**, From the back-end I am getting a **SET** which contains some information related to an user.

As I will have to show the values coming in **SET** on the front end so I will have to iterate SET and get the values.

How can I iterate SET in the html files in any angular project (**app.component.html**, I am writing this name as it is common to every project).??

Any Input will be appropriated..

Attaching the Code:

```
<ul>
        <li *ngFor="let user of users">
            {{user.username}}

            <!-- - <a (click)="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</a> -->
            {{user.roles}}
        </li>
    </ul>
```

`{{user.roles}}` gives me a set of roles for a user but It is not printing the values it is printing only the object.
I know it will print the object but how can i get the value.

Comment: you can user *ngFor to iterate items

Comment: @ShakeerHussain I tried with ngFor, it is not showing the value on the UI, it is printing like **[object Object]**

Comment: If you try to display an object in a browser it will just show you  [object Object].  You want to display a value contained in the object.  Say you have ngFor="let o of objects", you want to display {{o.name}} instead of {{o}}

Comment: @GMK I am displaying {{o.name}} only but that o.name gives me a SET of values that I want to display on UI, if i display only {{o.name}} is gives me [object Object] only

Comment: It sounds like you have a set of objects each of which contains another set.  If that's the case, just use another (nested) ngFor to iterate the set contained in the object.

Comment: @GMK I have attached the code snippet, Can you please check

Comment: @Deepak, Looks like Users object is returning null. So you are seeing object Object]. To check write Console.Log(Users| json), it will display if there is a data in log>

Comment: @GMK Users object is not null, because I am getting the correct username from this expression : {{user.username}}

Comment: Okay, then roles might be role having null values. debug by using console.log(users | json)

Comment: If {{user.roles}} is a set of values you need to use another ngFor.  Instead of just {{user.roles}} try <li ngFor="let role of user.roles"> and inside that try {{role}}.  If role is a string it should print your values.

Comment: @GMK I got it resolved.. Actually I was using lombok which is actually a library which automatically generated the getters setters for the field in java pojo class. I was relying on this but when I debugged the code, getters and setters were not getting generated. Problem was with getter and setter. Roles class was not having getter and setter so jason was not able to figure out the things about Roles. Finally when I created getter and setter for this, it started working.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the `*ngFor` directive to iterate over the data you get from your backend just like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}} - {{item | json}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

apparently, your backend is returning the data wrapped in an object this is why I included the json pipe so you can see the entire object printed on the screen and then decide what you are going to print on the screen using the dot notation to reach the actual values just like this:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    {{i}} - {{item?.value}}
  </li>
</ul>
```